# Check if a text returned is true or false

Tags: php, ajax

I have an Ajax/PHP code, I would like to check if the returned text is true or false:

```
$(".gets").click(function() {

    // some details

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "step2.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {

            // This is the button to hide
            $('.nums').fadeOut('fast');

        } // end function
    }); // end ajax  

    return false;
});
```

step2.php

```
if($num < 3) {
echo 'please choose at least 3 nums<br />';
$hideButton = false; // hide show nums button
} else {        
$hideButton = true;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo `$hideButton`. That info will be available then in `data`

```
if($num < 3) {
echo 'please choose at least 3 nums<br />';
    $hideButton = false; // hide show nums button
} else {        
    $hideButton = true;
}
echo $hideButton;
```

then -

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "step2.php",
   data: dataString,
   success: function(data) { // data now has the value of $hideButton
       if(data == 'true') {
          // This is the button to hide
          $('.nums').fadeOut('fast');
       }
    } // end function
}); // end ajax
```

Comment: Then it sounds like PHP is not running. Are you doing thisd on a web server? Or are you loading the files locally?

Comment: PHP is not running!!!!! how come??? I am not using json, I am using PHP / Ajax, so if I call step2.php I receive back the full code in step2.php (using alert and console)

Comment: what you  sending in dataString as post...?

Comment: Is there more on step2.php that you have not shown us? the echo, as I see it now, will contain a lot of text and then the state of `$hideButtons`. Because of that you would have to parse the data that you receive back to find the true/false and have it act properly.

Comment: here you go the full code of step2.phpthat will call again step3.php http://pastebin.com/6US9cAP1

Comment: From the looks of it you're going to need to re-think what you want to do. Each step in your process echos out a bunch of text that would have to be parsed once returned by AJAX - not a really good plan in this case. If you need to return a single data point (true or false) then you need to create a page that will only return that data.

Comment: how can I parse my data?

Comment: Without seeing everything that the page returns it would be hard to say.  It is also hard to say what design changes you could make to accommodate using AJAX because you haven't told us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gets").click(function() {

// some details

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "step2.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(data) {
              if(data == 'true')
                   {// your if code
                      }
             else
                  {// your else code
                   }

    // This is the button to hide
    $('.nums').fadeOut('fast');
} // end function
    }); // end ajax        
return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing your scripts like below.

In `AJAX success`

```
success: function(data) {
   if(data == 'false'){
      $('.nums').fadeOut('fast');
   }else{
      // other event if you want
   }
```

In `step2.php`

```
echo ( $num < 3 ) ? 'false' : 'true';
```

Comment: it is returning the code of step2.php on the alert box, step2.php starts with <head> and so on